# Uploading file using Angular/Cordova

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova

I'm trying to post a `FormData` object via `$http` provider in AngularJs.

In browser, it's possible to append file value of `input[type=file]` to `FormData` and post it via `$http`. something like:

```
formData.append('file', inp.files[0], 'nai.jpg');
formData.append('text', 'hello');
$http.post('url', formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
});
```

And server got post request with two body fields. But in Cordova apps, `input[type=file]` is not available, so i can get `fileURI` from user by native plugins like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(fileURI) {
    // i got fileURI
});
```

Now, Please explain me how can i put `fileURI` as file to `formData` and send that by `$http` provider of Angular (not `FileTransfer`).

Answer (score 0):

Cordova also gives the base64 data of the image, if we specify option in configuration object. so that you can pass the same base64 data to the service.

```
var cameraOptions = {
   destinationType : 0 /*(DATA_URL -- For base64 data)*/
}
navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, cameraOptions);
```

Comment: thx. yes but this way is too heavy. imagine that i should keep 5mb string into javascript variable before i submit that.